# POST /V1/order/:order_id/invoices,it gives wrong response in magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, partial-invoice

Suppose I have two products in order,one is simple product and other is bundle product.When i generate first simple product invoice using item_id of simple product using this body:

```
{
  "capture": false,
  "items": [
    {"order_item_id": 1249,"qty": 1}
  ],
  "notify": false,
  "appendComment": false,
  "comment": {
    "extension_attributes": {},
    "comment": "string",
    "is_visible_on_front": 0
  },
  "arguments": {
    "extension_attributes": {}
  }
}
```

It show response about simple product information and also bundle parent_item id.What is issue?

Comment: This is screenshot of invoice which are generated by /V1/order/:order_id/invoice:      https://i.stack.imgur.com/49OQy.png

Comment: can u say what should i pass in body to get invoice.

Comment: No, I will pass this data { "items": [ {"order_item_id": 1249,"qty": 1} ] }.But it generate wrong invoice details simple product and bundle parent_item detail is showing @PratapvarmaPenmetsa

Comment: {
    "message": "Request does not match any route.",
    "trace": null
}
i am getting this response
/V1/order/51/invoice 51 is my order_id

Comment: Please check method is POST.

Comment: i am using post method only

Comment: I will check on Magento Official website it show * POST /V1/order/:orderId/invoice.

Comment: i am using the same endpoint but i couldn't get the response

Comment: Please follow all steps again for creationg order and generate order after that check.

Comment: You check that @PratapvarmaPenmetsa

Comment: yes i  got invoice_id

Comment: If order have 2 items,both are bundle products.It also show wrong response.Please help me to  solve this issue.